# Using sorting variable in doBy functions

Tags: r

I have noticed a strange phenomenon that I'd like a sanity check on.

When I assign a letter to the name of variable (e.g., z`<-Type or z=Type`) where Type is a variable in a dataframe, yf, I can use `z` as a sorting variable for functions like making a linear model (e.g.,`aa=lm(y~z)`) or making boxplots (e.g., `boxplot(formula=y~z)`, but `z` doesn't work in the doBy functions. In other words `r=summaryBy(y~z, data = yf, FUN= c(mean, var, mystderr), na.rm=TRUE)` doesn't sort `y` by `z`, but `r=summaryBy(y~Type, data=yf, Fun=c(mean,var, mystderr), na.rm=TRUE)` works like a charm.

Does this make any sense? My program works just fine when I call the sorting variable directly, but I wasted a fair amount of time getting to this point.